# Extracting Information From table in sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have following structure in SQLServer 2008 R2

```
Emp_ID     Skill_ID     Skill_Name   _Skill_Level_ID   Skill_Level

 1           1           Carpenter       1              Beginner
 2           1           Mechanic        2              Advanced 
 3           2           Doctor          3              Moderate
 .           .
 .           .
 .           .
```

I want following output:

```
Skill_Name      Skill_Level   Count

Carpenter        Beginner     10
Carpenter        Moderate     12
Mechanic         Advanced     10
Mechanic         Moderate     10
```

I have tried various group by query but did not work.please guide me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this simple query could bring your results:

```
SELECT Skill_Name, Skill_Level,   Count(*) Counts
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Skill_Name, Skill_Level
ORDER BY Skill_Name
```

Comment: Thanks very much Indeed Kaf.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select COUNT(skill_id),skill_name,skill_level from skill group by skill_id,skill_name,skill_level
```